# Computation theory, finding the number of total injections from a set $B$ to $A\times B$ with $A = \{a,b,c,d,e\}$ $B = \{0,1,2\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The cardinality of $A \times B$ is $15$ and that's as far as I've gotten.I'm using Sudkamps book and computation theory and this seems to be a question on my next exam however it is not included in the book. I don't know how to approach the problem however I know the answer is $2730$.

Also: $|\mathcal{P}(B)| = 2^3 = 8$. What is the number of total injections from $A$ to $|\mathcal{P}(B)|$?

Please give a book recommendation that examines counting and compuatbility in great detail that examines these topics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The injections you want are the functions $f : B \rightarrow A \times B$ such that the three elements of $B$ - $0$, $1$, and $2$ - satisfy $$f(0) \neq f(1) \qquad f(1) \neq f(2) \qquad f(0) \neq f(2)$$

To find the number of possible functions $f$, we can count the number of ways to explicitly state the values of $f$ at $0$, $1$, and $2$.

We can choose what $0$ goes to in $15$ different ways, since as you observed, $A \times B$ has cardinality $15$. Given this, we can choose what $1$ goes to in $14$ different ways (it can't go to the same thing that $0$ went to). Given *this*, we can choose what $2$ goes to in $13$ ways.

Our final answer is thus

$$15 \cdot 14 \cdot 13 = \boxed{2730}$$

Comment: +1  Again,worth noting this combinatorial solution only works here because the sets under consideration are finite.

Answer (score 1):

To make an injection from a set $C$ to a set $D$, think of listing the elements of $C$ in order. The first one has $|D|$ choices of where to go.  The next one has $|D|-1$ choices, because it can pick any element of $D$ except the one that is taken.  The third has $|D|-2$ and so on.  It doesn't matter what $D$ is, just how many elements it has.

Comment: It's worth noting that this works in this case because the sets under consideration are at most countable-in fact,they're finite. For infinite sets, this is more problematic.

Comment: @Mathemagician1234:  Absolutely right.  The way  the question is stated made me confident we were in the finite realm.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ and $B$ be two finite sets such that $|A|=m$ and $|B|=n.$

Case(i). If $m<n,$ then the number of injections from $A$ to $B$ is $n(n-1)(n-2)\dots(n-(m-1)).$

For, The number of ways of choosing the image of first element, say  $x_1$, in $A$ is $n.$

The number of ways of choosing the image of second element, $x_2$, in $A$ is $n-1.$ 
(here -1 because $f(x_1)\neq f(x_2))$

The number of ways of choosing the image of third element, $x_3$, in $A$ is $n-2.$ (here -2 because $ f(x_3)\neq f(x_1)$ and $f(x_3)\neq f(x_2)).$

and so on...

Hence the total number of injections from $A$ to $B$ is $n(n-1)(n-2)\dots(n-(m-1)).$ {Thanks to multiplication principle in Combinatorics}.

Case(ii). If $m=n,$ then by the same technique in case (i), we have the total number of injections from $A$ to $B$ is $n!$

Case(iii). If $m>n,$ there is no injection from $A$ to $B.$

Reference: Introductory Combinatorics by Richard A. Brualdi